# compiling hunspell-1.3.2 with cygwin in win 7 ultimate

Tags: compilation, cygwin, hunspell

I need hunspell. I am a windows user. I am using win 7 ultimate English.

OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name NURAS-PC
System Manufacturer Sony Corporation
System Model    VPCW21M1E
System Type x64-based PC
Processor   Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N450   @ 1.66GHz, 1666 Mhz, 1 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   INSYDE R0240E2, 07-Dec-09
SMBIOS Version  2.6
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "6.1.7601.17514"
User Name   nuras-PC\nuras
Time Zone   Turkey Daylight Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 2.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   1.99 GB
Available Physical Memory   704 MB
Total Virtual Memory    4.23 GB
Available Virtual Memory    1.84 GB
Page File Space 2.24 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys

Yesterday I installed Cygwin x86 all packages written in hunspell read me. 
2. Compiling in Cygwin environment
make
gcc-g++ development package
mingw development package (for cygwin.dll free native Windows compilation)
ncurses, readline (for user interface)
iconv (character conversion)
I selected nearly all dev and util packages
firstly I pasted my "C:\cygwin\bin\cygwin1.dll" to "c:\Windows\system32\"
the first time pushed the Cygwin console wrote the command "mkdir dene"
then I added the path the windows path
my downloaded hunspell I unzipped two times with 7zip and copied pasted to under "dene" directory
then pushed Cygwin console

nuras@nuras-PC ~
$ cd dene

nuras@nuras-PC ~/dene
$ ls
hunspell-1.3.2

```
nuras@nuras-PC ~/dene
$ cd hunspell-1.3.2

nuras@nuras-PC ~/dene/hunspell-1.3.2
$ ./configure --with-ui
checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking target system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 8192
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... file_magic ^x86 archive import|^x86 DLL
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking dependency style of g++... (cached) gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking for objdump... (cached) objdump
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking libintl.h usability... no
checking libintl.h presence... no
checking for libintl.h... no
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking error.h usability... yes
checking error.h presence... yes
checking for error.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking for error_at_line... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for memchr... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for msgfmt... no
checking for gmsgfmt... :
checking for xgettext... no
checking for msgmerge... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C Library 2 or newer... no
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
checking for simple visibility declarations... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking whether integer division by zero raises SIGFPE... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for unsigned long long int... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking whether the inttypes.h PRIxNN macros are broken... no
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for ld used by GCC... /usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for shared library run path origin... done
checking whether imported symbols can be declared weak... yes
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for pthread_kill in -lpthread... yes
checking for pthread_rwlock_t... yes
checking for multithread API to use... posix
checking argz.h usability... yes
checking argz.h presence... yes
checking for argz.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... (cached) yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for getegid... yes
checking for geteuid... yes
checking for getgid... yes
checking for getuid... yes
checking for mempcpy... yes
checking for munmap... yes
checking for stpcpy... yes
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for tsearch... yes
checking for argz_count... yes
checking for argz_stringify... yes
checking for argz_next... yes
checking for __fsetlocking... no
checking whether feof_unlocked is declared... no
checking whether fgets_unlocked is declared... no
checking for iconv... yes
checking for working iconv... yes
checking how to link with libiconv... -liconv
checking for iconv declaration... install-shextern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
checking for NL_LOCALE_NAME macro... no
checking for bison... no
checking for long long int... yes
checking for wchar_t... yes
checking for wint_t... yes
checking for intmax_t... yes
checking whether printf() supports POSIX/XSI format strings... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C Library 2.1 or newer... no
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for SIZE_MAX... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking for ptrdiff_t... yes
checking stddef.h usability... yes
checking stddef.h presence... yes
checking for stddef.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking for asprintf... yes
checking for fwprintf... yes
checking for putenv... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for setlocale... (cached) yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking for wcslen... yes
checking whether _snprintf is declared... no
checking whether _snwprintf is declared... no
checking whether getc_unlocked is declared... yes
checking for nl_langinfo and CODESET... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking for windres... windres
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... (cached) no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... (cached) no
checking whether included gettext is requested... no
checking for GNU gettext in libc... no
checking for GNU gettext in libintl... no
checking whether to use NLS... yes
checking where the gettext function comes from... included intl directory
checking for tparm in -lncursesw... yes
Compiling with curses user interface.
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating hunspell.pc
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating man/hu/Makefile
config.status: creating intl/Makefile
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating m4/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/hunspell/Makefile
config.status: creating src/hunspell/hunvisapi.h
config.status: creating src/parsers/Makefile
config.status: creating src/tools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/win_api/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/suggestiontest/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing po-directories commands
config.status: creating po/POTFILES
config.status: creating po/Makefile

nuras@nuras-PC ~/dene/hunspell-1.3.2
$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2'
Making all in intl
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/intl'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/intl'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/po'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/po'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/src'
Making all in hunspell
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/src/hunspell'
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT affentry.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/affentry.Tpo -c -o affentry.lo affentry.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT affentry.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/affentry.Tpo -c affentry.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/affentry.o
In file included from affentry.cxx:9:0:
affentry.hxx:30:105: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘short unsigned int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
   struct hentry *      check_twosfx(const char * word, int len, char in_compound, const FLAG needflag = NULL);
                                                                                                         ^
affentry.hxx:93:114: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘short unsigned int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
   struct hentry *   check_twosfx(const char * word, int len, int optflags, PfxEntry* ppfx, const FLAG needflag = NULL);
                                                                                                                  ^
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT affentry.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/affentry.Tpo -c affentry.cxx -o affentry.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/affentry.Tpo .deps/affentry.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT affixmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/affixmgr.Tpo -c -o affixmgr.lo affixmgr.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT affixmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/affixmgr.Tpo -c affixmgr.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/affixmgr.o
In file included from affixmgr.cxx:12:0:
affentry.hxx:30:105: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘short unsigned int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
   struct hentry *      check_twosfx(const char * word, int len, char in_compound, const FLAG needflag = NULL);
                                                                                                         ^
affentry.hxx:93:114: warning: converting to non-pointer type ‘short unsigned int’ from NULL [-Wconversion-null]
   struct hentry *   check_twosfx(const char * word, int len, int optflags, PfxEntry* ppfx, const FLAG needflag = NULL);
                                                                                                                  ^
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT affixmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/affixmgr.Tpo -c affixmgr.cxx -o affixmgr.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/affixmgr.Tpo .deps/affixmgr.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT csutil.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/csutil.Tpo -c -o csutil.lo csutil.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT csutil.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/csutil.Tpo -c csutil.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/csutil.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT csutil.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/csutil.Tpo -c csutil.cxx -o csutil.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/csutil.Tpo .deps/csutil.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT dictmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/dictmgr.Tpo -c -o dictmgr.lo dictmgr.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT dictmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/dictmgr.Tpo -c dictmgr.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/dictmgr.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT dictmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/dictmgr.Tpo -c dictmgr.cxx -o dictmgr.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/dictmgr.Tpo .deps/dictmgr.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hashmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashmgr.Tpo -c -o hashmgr.lo hashmgr.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hashmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashmgr.Tpo -c hashmgr.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/hashmgr.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hashmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hashmgr.Tpo -c hashmgr.cxx -o hashmgr.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/hashmgr.Tpo .deps/hashmgr.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hunspell.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hunspell.Tpo -c -o hunspell.lo hunspell.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hunspell.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hunspell.Tpo -c hunspell.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/hunspell.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hunspell.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hunspell.Tpo -c hunspell.cxx -o hunspell.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/hunspell.Tpo .deps/hunspell.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT suggestmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/suggestmgr.Tpo -c -o suggestmgr.lo suggestmgr.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT suggestmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/suggestmgr.Tpo -c suggestmgr.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/suggestmgr.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT suggestmgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/suggestmgr.Tpo -c suggestmgr.cxx -o suggestmgr.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/suggestmgr.Tpo .deps/suggestmgr.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT phonet.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/phonet.Tpo -c -o phonet.lo phonet.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT phonet.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/phonet.Tpo -c phonet.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/phonet.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT phonet.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/phonet.Tpo -c phonet.cxx -o phonet.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/phonet.Tpo .deps/phonet.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT filemgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/filemgr.Tpo -c -o filemgr.lo filemgr.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT filemgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/filemgr.Tpo -c filemgr.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/filemgr.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT filemgr.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/filemgr.Tpo -c filemgr.cxx -o filemgr.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/filemgr.Tpo .deps/filemgr.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hunzip.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hunzip.Tpo -c -o hunzip.lo hunzip.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hunzip.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hunzip.Tpo -c hunzip.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/hunzip.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT hunzip.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/hunzip.Tpo -c hunzip.cxx -o hunzip.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/hunzip.Tpo .deps/hunzip.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..    -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT replist.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/replist.Tpo -c -o replist.lo replist.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT replist.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/replist.Tpo -c replist.cxx  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o .libs/replist.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -MT replist.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/replist.Tpo -c replist.cxx -o replist.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/replist.Tpo .deps/replist.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++ -fvisibility=hidden -DBUILDING_LIBHUNSPELL -g -O2 -no-undefined  -o libhunspell-1.3.la -rpath /usr/local/lib affentry.lo affixmgr.lo csutil.lo dictmgr.lo hashmgr.lo hunspell.lo suggestmgr.lo phonet.lo filemgr.lo hunzip.lo replist.lo
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libhunspell-1.3.a .libs/libhunspell-1.3.dll.a .libs/libhunspell-1.3.la .libs/libhunspell-1.3.lai
libtool: link: g++ -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/crtbegin.o  .libs/affentry.o .libs/affixmgr.o .libs/csutil.o .libs/dictmgr.o .libs/hashmgr.o .libs/hunspell.o .libs/suggestmgr.o .libs/phonet.o .libs/filemgr.o .libs/hunzip.o .libs/replist.o   -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../.. -lstdc++ -lgcc_s -lgcc -lcygwin -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/crtend.o    -o .libs/cyghunspell-1.3-0.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libhunspell-1.3.dll.a
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libhunspell-1.3.a  affentry.o affixmgr.o csutil.o dictmgr.o hashmgr.o hunspell.o suggestmgr.o phonet.o filemgr.o hunzip.o replist.o
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libhunspell-1.3.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libhunspell-1.3.la" && ln -s "../libhunspell-1.3.la" "libhunspell-1.3.la" )
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/src/hunspell'
Making all in parsers
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/src/parsers'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..     -g -O2 -MT firstparser.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/firstparser.Tpo -c -o firstparser.o firstparser.cxx
mv -f .deps/firstparser.Tpo .deps/firstparser.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..     -g -O2 -MT htmlparser.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/htmlparser.Tpo -c -o htmlparser.o htmlparser.cxx
mv -f .deps/htmlparser.Tpo .deps/htmlparser.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..     -g -O2 -MT latexparser.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/latexparser.Tpo -c -o latexparser.o latexparser.cxx
mv -f .deps/latexparser.Tpo .deps/latexparser.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..     -g -O2 -MT manparser.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/manparser.Tpo -c -o manparser.o manparser.cxx
mv -f .deps/manparser.Tpo .deps/manparser.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../..     -g -O2 -MT textparser.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/textparser.Tpo -c -o textparser.o textparser.cxx
mv -f .deps/textparser.Tpo .deps/textparser.Po
rm -f libparsers.a
ar cru libparsers.a firstparser.o htmlparser.o latexparser.o manparser.o textparser.o
ranlib libparsers.a
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2   -o testparser.exe firstparser.o htmlparser.o latexparser.o manparser.o testparser.o textparser.o ../hunspell/libhunspell-1.3.la
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/testparser.exe firstparser.o htmlparser.o latexparser.o manparser.o testparser.o textparser.o  ../hunspell/.libs/libhunspell-1.3.dll.a -L/usr/local/lib
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/src/parsers'
Making all in tools
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/src/tools'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/hunspell -I../../src/parsers    -g -O2 -MT analyze.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/analyze.Tpo -c -o analyze.o analyze.cxx
mv -f .deps/analyze.Tpo .deps/analyze.Po
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2   -o analyze.exe analyze.o ../hunspell/libhunspell-1.3.la
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/analyze.exe analyze.o  ../hunspell/.libs/libhunspell-1.3.dll.a -L/usr/local/lib
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/hunspell -I../../src/parsers    -g -O2 -MT chmorph.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/chmorph.Tpo -c -o chmorph.o chmorph.cxx
mv -f .deps/chmorph.Tpo .deps/chmorph.Po
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2   -o chmorph.exe chmorph.o ../parsers/libparsers.a ../hunspell/libhunspell-1.3.la
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/chmorph.exe chmorph.o  ../parsers/libparsers.a ../hunspell/.libs/libhunspell-1.3.dll.a -L/usr/local/lib
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../src/hunspell -I../../src/parsers    -g -O2 -MT hunspell.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/hunspell.Tpo -c -o hunspell.o hunspell.cxx
hunspell.cxx:119:21: fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ncurses.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:524: recipe for target 'hunspell.o' failed
make[3]: *** [hunspell.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/src/tools'
Makefile:329: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2/src'
Makefile:425: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nuras/dene/hunspell-1.3.2'
Makefile:330: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think I forgot the installing "readline package" I will try to install now.

if I succeed the compilation which directory will Cygwin  put it the huspell's executables?
if anyone give me some help I will be appreciated. Thank you.
art

Comment: Looks like you're missing the libncursesw-devel package. As for where it will install it, that depends upon how it was configured. You didn't supply any options to configure, so it will go into the default directory supplied by the package creator. This is usually /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin. Typically, you can provide a `--prefix=<dir>` option to configure, such as `--prefix=/opt` and then it will be installed in the bin directory under your prefix folder.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above, it does look like that you're missing libncursesw-devel. You can install that from the setup application that you used to install Cygwin.

I've downloaded the source for hunspell-1.3.2 and built it successfully on my machine.

I can now tell you that by default it installs into /usr/local.

Also, for better performance, you should add "--enable-shared=yes" to your configure command line options and add LDFLAGS="-no-undefined" to your options when you call "make". This will force the build scripts to build a shared library for libhunspell.

Finally, hunspell's configure script aborts almost immediately under 64-bit Cygwin, complaining that it can't recognize the system type. Since I notice that you're using 32-bit Cygwin, I did not do any research into how difficult this would be to correct. Fixing configure is probably pretty trivial, but that doesn't guarantee that hunspell will compile and run.